# get all rows from table that have both variables in a same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all company ids from a table that have both city ids (let's say 7333 and 10906) but id doesn't work the way I do it.

This is my table:

[image]

and this is my code

```
   SELECT `company_id` as id 
   FROM `logistics_companies_destinations` 
   WHERE `city_id`= 7333 and `city_id` = 10906
```

Comment: `city_id` cannot be *both* of the values at the same time.

Comment: Yeah I got that but what is the workaround for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also solve this using an `INNER JOIN` to the table itself, joining on the same `company_id` and requiring both city_ids to be present:

```
SELECT
        `lcd1`.`company_id` AS id 
   FROM `logistics_companies_destinations` AS lcd1
   INNER JOIN `logistics_companies_destinations` AS lcd2
   WHERE `lcd1`.`city_id`= 7333 AND `lcd2`.`city_id` = 10906
```

*Sorry, I usually also frown upon stupidly abbreviated table names like this, but did not come up with better aliases ;)*

Comment: Which one is better - with INNER JOIN or with nested sql query ?

Comment: "Which one is better " - the one that is easier to understand and most clearly shows the intent. I prefer the join technique but I think beginners find the subselect/IN easier to understand. The execution plans should be identical.

Comment: Yea, I second that the plans should really be identical, however I do not run MySQL here so I cannot say for sure. But to add to that I also prefer joins over nested queries almost always because they are easier to read and save lots of indentation space ;)

Comment: Thank you both very much :)

Answer (score 4):

MySQL does not have an `INTERSECT` keyword, but one way to implement this is:

```
   SELECT `company_id` as id 
   FROM `logistics_companies_destinations` 
   WHERE 
        `city_id` = 10906
        and `company_id` IN (SELECT `company_id` as id 
                             FROM `logistics_companies_destinations` 
                             WHERE `city_id`= 7333)
```

[Another way (as note by another poster) is to join to the table twice and apply the filter conditions one to each join].

Comment: Which one is better - with INNER JOIN or with nested sql query ?

Comment: "Which one is better " - the one that is easier to understand and most clearly shows the intent. I prefer the join technique but I think beginners find the subselect/IN easier to understand. The execution plans should be identical.

Comment: @MitchWheat just one stupid question to finish this, did you show the nested query approach this time because you wanted to make it beginner friendly? (as you say you prefer joins yourself...)

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is the "and". You are looking for the company_id if the city_id equals "7333" AND "10906". Use an or and it should work.

Comment: OP wants companies for which both city_ids occur not those for which at least one of them does

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Like Siyual said city_id cannot equal 7333 **and** 10906. So the answer is correct. The OP needs **OR**, not **AND**.

Comment: read the first sentence of the question again, it does not say `rows that have both city_ids` it says `companies` and as you see from the sample data a company can occur multiple times throughout the table in different rows ;)